# Comparison operators in string format convert to actual operator

Tags: vb.net

I have the following table in vb.net this is not my data but I need to use it so it is what it is

```
column   condition    value    icon
c1       equals       1        127
c1       greater than 10       128
c1       equals       5        129
```

what I need to do is take each row evaluate the data so I can set the icon depending on value of `myvalue` like the following  the ????? would be the comparison operator converted from `row("condition")` .

```
dim myvalue as integer = 5
dim newiconnum as integer = 1
for each row in dt.rows
     if myvalue ????? row("value") then
        newiconnum = row("icon")
     end if
next
```

what I don't understand is how to make the ?????  into the actually comparison operator as in "equals" is = and "greater than" is > from the condition table

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as "visual studio operators". You have language-specific operators

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion comes from what to do with the operator/condition.. the following should place you on the path.

```
Select Case row("condition").ToString.Trim.ToLower
    Case "equals"
        If myvalue = row("value")
            newiconnum = row("icon")
        End If

    Case "greater than"
        If myvalue < row("value")      '  assuming the row("value") is gt myvalue
            newiconnum = row("icon")
        End If
End Select
```